# How to remove history repo/ folder in my projects?

Tags: vscode-extensions, history

So basically, whenever I start coding a project, I see this (.history) folder popping up and it contains all the files containing different changes. Like I might have a file called app.js in my project and there will be that file in this folder at different stages of coding basically like a git commit changes. So can someone tell me how to disable this folder to ever come in my projects, it's really very irritating.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not from Git, unless you yourself added that folder at some point in time. In other words, I'd suspect the culprit in "whenever I start coding a project", whatever you do then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. If you have installed the Local Storage extension in your VSCode editor DELETE it. That is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your repository and run git filter-repo with the path to the folder you no longer need AND the option --invert-paths – otherwise you remove all but the Template/ folder:

```
$ git filter-repo --path Templates/ --invert-paths
```